# How to set an attribute value each time an event is triggered?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, implementation, state, state-machine

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.9 and I am just trying to use the [state_machine](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine) gem. I have following statements:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  state_machine :attribute => :status, :initial => :unconfirmed do
    state :confirmed, :value => 'confirmed'
    state :unconfirmed, :value => 'unconfirmed'

    event :confirm do
      transition :unconfirmed => :confirmed
    end

    event :unconfirm do
      transition :confirmed => :unconfirmed
    end
  end
end
```

I have also a `confirmed_at` attribute for the `Article` model intended to keep the last time when the `:status` switches to `:confirmed`.

How to initialize the `confirmed_at` attribute to the current time? How *should* I set the `confirmed_at` to the current time each time the `:confirm` event is triggered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like that's what `before_transition` is for.

```
before_transition :confirmed => any - :confirmed, :do => :set_confirmed_at
```

Then add a method by that name:

```
def set_confirmed_at
  self.confirmed_at = Time.now
end
```

Comment: How to initialize the `confirmed_at` attribute to the current time?

Comment: How does the `set_confirmed_at` method not do that?

Comment: I mean cases when the object is a *new* object and doesn't change status (that is, when the `confirm` event isn't triggered).

Comment: Still not sure what you're after exactly, but it sounds more like active model callbacks: `before_create :set_confirmed_at`

Comment: OK, so I have to use a RoR' callback in order to set "initial values" (and not to make the same by using the `state_machine` gem).